# Question about subset of $ \ell^2 $ space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, advice

I have some doubts regarding a problem that I found in notes about metric spaces.

We have the set  A of sequences that satisfy $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ({a}_{i})^2 \lt \infty $. This is the $ \ell^2$ space.  The summation of each squared term of the sequence is a finite number. The metric is defined as $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (({a}_{i} - {b}_{i})^2)^{1/2} $

The first part of the problem is : If we take the set of sequences $ X=   \{ (1,0,0,…,0,0…); (0,1,0,0,…0,…); … ; (0,0,0,…,1,0,…);… \} $, we need to show that X belongs to $ \ell^2 $

Unless I am missing something, it seem pretty trivial : We need to show that, since any sequence in X has only one non zero term, the summation of only one non zero term squared ($1^2$) is finite.

The second part is : To show that X is bounded and closed, but not compact in $ \ell ^2 $ . Here I am more doubtful , but I try :

1. Boundedness  :  We know that the distance of any element of X is either zero or $\sqrt 2$. So there is a $ r \gt 0$ such that for every element $x,y \in X  \space , d(x,y) \lt r$ . Therefore X is bounded
2. Closedness : Since the set X is a sphere with radius $ \sqrt 2 $, X is closed (I know this is true but I dont know the justification, so I would appreciate help here)
3. Compactness : Here I dont know how to show that X is not compact. I would appreciate some insight.

Thanks to all!

Comment: It's not actually a sphere, j ust the points on it are all square root of 2 apart.  There are other things on that sphere that are NOT in X.   Just show that any convergent sequence is eventually constant.  Will give hints in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. Boundedness is clear since $\|\mathbf{e}_n\|_2=1$ for all $n$
2. As for closeness, notice that if $\mathbf{e}_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}\mathbf{x}$, then $\{\mathbf{e}_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. For $0<\varepsilon<1$, there is $K_0$ such that for $k',k\geq K_0$,
   $$\|\mathbf{e}_{n_k}-\mathbf{e}_{n_{k'}}\|_2<\varepsilon$$
   Since $\|\mathbf{e}_{n}-\mathbf{e}_{m}\|_2=\sqrt{2}>1$ for all $m\neq n$, it follows that $\mathbf{e}_{n_k}=\mathbf{e}_{n_{K_0}}$ for all $k\geq K_0$. Therefore $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{e}_{n_{K_0}}$. This proves that $\{\mathbf{e}_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed.
3. Lack of compactness can be proved as in (2). Another way to see this is to consider the open cover $\{B(\mathbf{e}_n;\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $B(\mathbf{y};r)=\{\mathbf{z}\in\ell_2: \|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{z}\|_2<r\}$. This open cover has no finite subcover.

Comment: I have a question about Boundedness : Is there any relationship between using the fact that the norm is 1 for every element in X, and using the spheres-thing that Alan says? Or these two are two different ways of proving the same?

Comment: In linear spaces with norm, a set $A$ is bounded of there is an ball $B(\mathbf{0};r)$ such that $A\subset B(\mathbf{0};r)$. In the case of $A=\{\mathbf{e}_n:n\in\mathbb{B}\}$, $A\subset B(\mathbf{0};2)$ for example.

Comment: Thanks. In the part of Closedness the conclusion is that every limit point x is part of X right (because $ {e}_{n_{K_0}} $ is in X (Archimedian property?))?

Comment: Indeed, any point $x$ in the closure of $A=\{\mathbf{e}_n\}$ is in fact an element of $A$: $\overline{A}=A$.

Comment: I have one more doubt about Closedness. You write “ $\|\mathbf{e}_{n_k}-\mathbf{e}_{n_{k'}}\|_2 \lt \epsilon $” that is the distance between two terms of a same sequence. 
After that you write “ $\|\mathbf{e}_{n}-\mathbf{e}_{m}\| = \sqrt 2 $” that is, the distance between two different series. And then you conclude that the term k and K0 of the same sequence are the same. And that the term K0 of the sequence is the limit. I dont understand that reasoning. Can you explain this a little bit more? Sorry if i bother you.

Comment: Sorry, when I said distance it wanted to mean norm

Comment: My doubt is that one norm is between two terms of a same sequence. And the second is the norm between two different sequences. I dont understand that part. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I mean, I dont know how is possible to compare a norm of two terms of a sequence with a norm of two different sequences.

Comment: $(\mathbf{e}_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence whose elements are in $A=\{\mathbf{e}_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Thus, if $\mathbf{e}_{n_k}\neq\mathbf{e}_{n_{k'}}$, then $\|\mathbf{e}_{n_k}-\mathbf{e}_{n_{k'}}\|_2=\sqrt{2}$. With the choice of $0<\varepsilon<1$, one gets $K_0$ (which depends on $\varepsilon$) such that $\|\mathbf{e}_{n_k}-\mathbf{e}_{n_{k'}}\|_2<\varepsilon<\sqrt{2}$ whenever $k,k'\geq K_0$. In particular, for all $k\geq K_0$, $\|\mathbf{e}_{n_k}-\mathbf{e}_{n_{K_0}}\|_2<\varepsilon<\sqrt{2}$. Hence $\mathbf{e}_{n_k}=\mathbf{e}_{n_{K_0}}$ for all $k\geq K_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Showing $X$ is in your space is indeed that trivial  Bounded=it fits inside a sphere around a point,  here every point is ON the sphere around $0$ of radius $\sqrt 2$, so it sits in any bigger sphere.

For closed, your points are all a fixed discrete distance apart from each other.  So imagine you have a convergent sequence from $X, a_n$.  That means you can pick an $\epsilon$ that eventually all the points are that close to its limit, whatever that limit is.   So pick $\epsilon=.1$,  or something else sufficiently small to use the triangle inequality to show that from some $N$ on the sequence is constant.   That tells you the limit is that constant point, and hence in the space.

To show it is not compact,  just show an infinite open cover with no finite subcover.  Hint: Since your distinct points are all $\sqrt 2$ apart,  make each one a member of its own open set and no other,  thus there can be no finite subcover.

Edited to include the basic topological insight:  Basically if you look at the induced topology on $X$ you are getting an infinite discrete metric space.  The proofs for everything are identical for any infinite discrete metric space.

Comment: About the part of bounded : Basically, X fits in a sphere around 0 of radius $ \sqrt 2 $ and therefore X fits in any sphere around 0 of radius r > $ \sqrt 2 $ ? Thats the idea?

Comment: Yep.  The points in X lie exactly on that sphere, so it is bounded by any bigger sphere around 0

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more the part of closedness? I cannot visualize it yet. Sorry if I bother you.

Comment: In a metric space, you can the sequential property to check closed.  Namely if you have a _convergent_ sequence consisting of points in your subset,  then the limit is also in that subset.  For instance, $(0,1)$ is not closed in the reals because the sequence $a_n=\frac 1 n$ all comes from $(0,1)$, but it converges to $0$ which is not in the set.   Here,  if you assume a convergent sequence exists consisting of elements of your space, the only way for that to happen is if it is eventually constant,jj since distinct points are $\sqrt 2$ apart.  Thus the limit will be that constant and thus in.